# How to ignore session if a session had already been started?

Tags: php, html

I have a login page, and when I log in, it brings me to my home page. If the user doesn't log out and come back later, then he won't need to log in again. However, if a user is already logged in, then it will display an error message saying that a session has already been started and therefore, it's ignoring the following code.

This is my session.php file. I would like to add an if statement, saying that if the session is already started, then bring the user to the home page, and if the session is not started, then bring the user to the login page.

```
<?php
// mysqli_connect() function opens a new connection to the MySQL server. 
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "supercar"); 
session_start();// Starting Session
// Storing Session 
$user_check = $_SESSION['login_user']; 
// SQL Query To Fetch Complete Information Of User 
$query = "SELECT * from adminlogin where email = '$user_check'"; 
$ses_sql = mysqli_query($conn, $query); 
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($ses_sql); 
$login_session = $row['nom'];
$login_session2 = $row['id'];
$login_session3 = $row['motdepasse'];

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this  code:

```
if(!isset( $_SESSION['login_user'])){
   $_SESSION['login_user'];
} else {
   header("location:index.php");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$user = $_SESSION['login_user'];
if(isset($user) && $user != ''){
   $query = "SELECT * from adminlogin where email = '$user'"; 
   $ses_sql = mysqli_query($conn, $query); 
   $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($ses_sql); 
   $login_session = $row['nom'];
   $login_session2 = $row['id'];
   $login_session3 = $row['motdepasse'];
}else{
   header("location:index.php");
}
```

Comment: If empty usernames are not allowed then this will work. But won't this create a notice if the session is not started? $user will be empty and strlen of empty, won't that be an "uncountable variable"?

Answer (score 0):

Answers above can do the trick but you also need to check for session. if session is running and you go the web page where `session_start()` exists you'll get error
Use the code below.

```
if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
    session_start();
}
```

[checkout here session here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-status.php)

Answer (score 0):

empty() function will check that variable set or not with value empty or not. So you no need to compare it's value. If value vary then you need to compare values.

```
if(!empty($_SESSION['login_user'])):
   // Your session is already set
else:
   // Your session is not set yet
endif;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if(empty($SESSION['login_user'])){
  session_start(); //Start session and put session value
}else{
  //Redirect here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `session_id()` function will fetch the `id` of the current session, which is typically a random string. If the session hasn’t been started, it will return an empty string, which, of course, tests as `false`.

Using that knowledge, you can try something like:

```php
if(!session_id()) session_start();
```